# Schauder estimate with right hand side in $L^n$.

Tags: analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, holder-spaces

The classical Schauder estimate says that if $u$ is a solution of 
\begin{equation}
\Delta u = f
\end{equation}
where $f \in C^{\alpha}(B_1)$, then $u \in C^{2, \alpha}(B_{1/2})$. Moreover, we have
\begin{equation}
\|u\|_{C^{2, \alpha}(B_{1/2)}} \le C \{ \|u\|_{L^\infty(B_1)} + \|f\|_{C^\alpha(B_1)} \}.
\end{equation} 
There are other "Schauder estimates" and I'm looking for one where $f \in L^n$ where $n$ is the dimension of the space, in order to obtain the Hölder regularity of the solution. I will be very grateful.